# How to stream to a zip using NodeJS and Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, filesystems

I'm new to JavaScript / NodeJS so forgive me for what's likely a basic question. But I'm trying to understand something fundamental.

We've a project structured like so

- Bottom layer is made up of a re-usable NodeJS SDK
- This is being bundled by Browserify
- The bundle is used with a local index.html (via JavaScript calls)

The current task I'm working on involves writing code in the SDK to

- Read data from a http REST API
- Format this data
- Create a zip on disk
- Write the formatted data to the zip

Then I need to write code in the index.html

- To supply a path
- Kick off the above steps to create a zip

As a starting point I've been playing with the standard NodeJS **fs** module. However when I browserify the code

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

translates fs to {}. There does seem to be a separate module [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) that'll allow me to support fs. But this issue has made me question the approach I'm taking.

- Is fs a good option to use for a browser?
- How common is it for browser JavaScript to support streaming to zip? i.e. As opposed to downloading a pre-existing zip from a http server.

Appreciate this question is open ended. But I'm curious to hear what the community thinks.

Comment: Why do you have to use `fs` in the browser? Doesn't make sense. Doesn't the zip creation happen on the server?

Comment: That was my reaction. But there's an encryption requirement that means it can only occur on the customer's side.